# Actionscript 3 for Android - should I attach mouse event listeners to the stage or to individual sprites?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-builder4.5

In AS3 on Android is it bad from a performance perspective to attach mouse event listeners to individual sprites rather than to the stage?

I am writing an app for an Android phone using AS3 in Flash Builder.  The app has multiple screens that respond to user touch.  The screens are arranged in a hierarchy and show list data so that when you click on an item in a list you are presented with a new screen with a new sub list on it.

I have been using an event listener to detect mouse / touch input and based on something I read that indicated that performance is much better if you keep the number of objects you are listening to to a minimum I have attached the mouse listeners from each screen to the stage object.

This all works fine but I am finding that as I move between screens (and they get popped or pushed onto the dislay stack) I have to keep track of alot of adding and removing listeners to the stage object.  If I don't then windows higher up the hierarchy than the current screen keep receiving mouse events.

If I used listeners attached to sprites in each window then when the window was removed from the display even though it is kept in memory (ready to be popped back when a child window is closed) it won't receive any mouse events....

Performance doesn't seem to be impacted using listeners directly on sprites when using my HTC phone to test with, however I obviously don't know what it will be like on other phones.  Does anyone have any experience either way or a view on the best approach?

Comment: When you attach a Listener to the stage, you then have to check the coordinates of the event to match it to a sprite? or how do you do that?

Comment: There are localToGlobal functions on display objects that do that conversion.  In this particular case though the sprites are almost full screen so the conversion is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use Listeners on specific sprites, as it will be easier to code and maintain, also coordinates conversion might get cumbersome to manage with different screen/sprites sizes, and removing/adding listeners might not be so easy to maintain as you add more screens...

As for performance, I don't believe Listeners will have any impact, it is just a function that get called when the sprite is clicked, if you don't set a Listener, the OS registers the click anyway and sends it down to the lower level View until it eventually finds a Listener to the event, or drops it.

Comment: I've updated the code to use listeners on sprites and the performance seems fine.  However, I am only using a very small number of sprites with listeners oncreen at the same time (<5) so the results may be different if you were listening to more objects...

Comment: thanks for the feedback, just to know, what device where you testing on?

Comment: HTC Desire, Samsung Galaxy Tab.